# Telegram bots read channel updates

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

As telegram bots reads groups updates, is there any way to read channel updates also?

Comment: you can add your bot to channel and check yourself

Comment: @Slavik I did it but bot couldn't read channel updates.

Comment: there is telegram-cli https://github.com/vysheng/tg client, you may try to watch updates through it

Answer (score 10):

At the moment, [Telegram Bots API](https://core.telegram.org/bots) doesn't allow bots to receive messages in channels, so it is not possible to read them (unless you use a [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/#telegram-api) one.

**Update**

Since [November update](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api-changelog#november-21-2016), the api now supports channel post and edition updates.

Comment: How can I join my bot into channels to get thier updates (channels which I am not thier admin) ?

Comment: At the moment, bots can only be added as admins to channels

Answer (score 4):

for not your channel:
if the channel is public, you can scrape from html code with address : `https://t.me/s/ChannelName/messageId`
if the channel is private, nothing to do

for your channel:
you can create a dummy group, then request '`forwardMessage`' to forward from channel to dummy group

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you only have to add the bot to your channel.

This is a **JSON RESPONSE**

{"update_id":164442191,
"channel_post":{"message_id":1405,"chat":{"id":-1001066700541,"title":"Underworld'S Creatures","username":"IlSottobosco","type":"channel"},"date":1499299471,"reply_to_message":{"message_id":1403,"chat":{"id":-100106670231,"title":"Underworld'S Creatures","username":"IlSottobosco","type":"channel"},"date":1499298047,"text":"Test"}}

Comment: Is there a way to get updates from a channel (not mine but where I am a subscriber) for every messages added? There are a lot of commercial bot that works but don't understand how they work

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just like groups and users update, but the difference is, you have to change **["message"]["text"]** with **["channel_post"]["text"]**.

Take a look at this code:

```
$update = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), TRUE);
$message = $update["message"]["text"]; // this will get users and groups messages.
$channel_post = $update["channel_post"]["text"]; // this will get messages send to the channel that bot is admin.
```